# Why use a VAR to measure data covariances?

Tags: time-series, covariance, vector-autoregression

Is there a reason why someone would estimate a VAR and then get the estimates of covariance of the data, instead of just using the usual sample covariance estimate formula for each observable variable?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How exactly would someone get the estimates of covariance of the data after having estimated a VAR? (Trying to understand what you mean by this.) If that is really happening, then perhaps they are after conditional covariance? The conditional distribution of the data can be obtained after modelling the data, while parameters of the unconditional distribution can be estimated directly by their sample counterparts.

Comment: @RichardHardy What I think they've done is estimate the covariances of the error term, and then apply an MA representation or something similar... It's also a doubt I have. This I've seen being done in Smets and Wouters 2003 paper, section 3.3.2

Comment: I think it must be the conditional covariance they are targeting. More generally, you do not necessarily need to think about this in the context of a relatively complicated model such as VAR; the basic logic should apply also for any regression model (if that helps).

Comment: @RichardHardy You mean the conditional covariance of the parameters estimators?

Comment: I mean the conditional covariance of dependent variables given independent variables.

Comment: Also, using a model rather than estimating covariance or other properties with their sample counterparts directly (nonparametrically) may be more efficient if we assume the model is correct. For example, if you want to estimate the median of a normal distribution efficiently, better use the mean of an i.i.d. sample from it. The sample mean is a more efficient estimator of the population median than the sample median is.